# Can't send substring to database

Tags: c#, sql-server, database

My goal is to send data from C# to SQL server, ut nothing happens in DB side. What can be the problem? Maybe its wrong data type in DB side?

Code for getting string and sending it.

Full code

```
namespace NIBP2PC
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private delegate void displayDeleg(string message);

        const string STX = "\u0002";    //Start
        const string ETX = "\u0003";    //End
        const string STARTMEAS = "01;;D7";  //Command Values
        const string STOPMEAS = "X";
        const string SETCYCLE0 = "03;;D9";  // Manual mode
        const string SETCYCLE1 = "04;;DA";  // 1 min
        const string SETCYCLE2 = "05;;DB";  // 2 min
        const string SETCYCLE3 = "06;;DC";  // 3 min
        const string SETCYCLE4 = "07;;DD";  // 4 min
        const string SETCYCLE5 = "08;;DE";  // 5 min
        const string SETCYCLE10 = "09;;DF"; // 10 min
        const string SETCYCLE15 = "10;;D7"; // 15 min
        const string SETCYCLE30 = "11;;D8"; // 30 min
        const string SETMANO = "14;;DB";  // Manometer mode
        const string SETREBOOT = "15;;DC";  // Reset Board
        const string SETLEAK = "17;;DE";  // Leakage Test
        const string READSTATUS = "18;;DF"; // Read Result
        const string SETPMP100 = "19;;E0";  // Set start pressure 100mmHg
        const string SETPMP120 = "20;;D8";  // Set start pressure 120mmHg
        const string SETPMP140 = "21;;D9";  // Set start pressure 140mmHg
        const string SETPMP160 = "22;;DA";  // Set start pressure 160mmHg
        const string SETPMP180 = "23;;DB";  // Set start pressure 180mmHg
        const string SETADULT = "24;;DC";  // Set Adult Mode
        const string SETNEO = "25;;DD";  // Set Neo Mode

        const byte INIT = 0;            //Not measured up to now
        const byte OK = 1;            // Status Values
        const byte RSTAT = 2;            // Read Status
        const byte RPRESS = 3;

        byte V_Cycle;
        byte V_Pumpup;
        int V_Map;

        // private VerticalProgressBar bar1 = new VerticalProgressBar();
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            list_comport();
        }
        private void list_comport()
        {
            // Get a list of serial port names. 
            string[] ports = SerialPort.GetPortNames();

            // Display each port name to the console. 
            foreach (string port in ports)
            {
                portToolStripMenuItem.DropDownItems.Add(port, null, new EventHandler(port_Click));
            }
        }

        private void port_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (serialPort1.IsOpen)
                serialPort1.Close();
            serialPort1.ReadBufferSize = 64;
            serialPort1.ReceivedBytesThreshold = 2;
            string Port = sender.ToString();
            serialPort1.PortName = Port;
            try
            {
                serialPort1.Open();
            }
            catch
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Serial port " + serialPort1.PortName +
                       " cannot be opened!", "RS232 tester",
                       MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);

            };
            toolStripStatusLabel_Com.Text = Port;

            Send_command(SETCYCLE0);
            Send_command(SETADULT);
            label_Status.Text = "IDLE";
            label_Cycle.Text = "Manual";
            label_Patient.Text = "Adult";
            label_Pump.Text = "160 mmHg";
            V_Cycle = 0;
            V_Pumpup = 3;
            Send_command(SETPMP160);
            Send_command(READSTATUS);        // Read status values
        }

        private void exitToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Application.Exit();
        }

        private void aboutToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            AboutBox1 about = new AboutBox1();
            about.Show();
        }

        private void button_Read_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Send_command(READSTATUS);
        }

        private void button_Cycle_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (label_Status.Text == "IDLE")
            {
                if (V_Cycle < 8)
                    V_Cycle++;
                else V_Cycle = 0;

                switch (V_Cycle)
                {
                    case 0:
                        Send_command(SETCYCLE0);
                        label_Cycle.Text = "Manual";
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        Send_command(SETCYCLE1);
                        label_Cycle.Text = "1 min";
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        Send_command(SETCYCLE2);
                        label_Cycle.Text = "2 min";
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        Send_command(SETCYCLE3);
                        label_Cycle.Text = "3 min";
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        Send_command(SETCYCLE4);
                        label_Cycle.Text = "4 min";
                        break;
                    case 5:
                        Send_command(SETCYCLE5);
                        label_Cycle.Text = "5 min";
                        break;
                    case 6:
                        Send_command(SETCYCLE10);
                        label_Cycle.Text = "10 min";
                        break;
                    case 7:
                        Send_command(SETCYCLE15);
                        label_Cycle.Text = "15 min";
                        break;
                    case 8:
                        Send_command(SETCYCLE30);
                        label_Cycle.Text = "30 min";
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
            }
        }

        private void Send_command(String command)
        {
            if (serialPort1.IsOpen)
            {
                serialPort1.Write(STX);     // STX = 2
                serialPort1.Write(command);
                serialPort1.Write(ETX);     // ETX = 3                  
            }
        }

        private void button_Patient_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (label_Status.Text == "IDLE")
            {
                if (label_Patient.Text == "Adult")
                {
                    Send_command(SETNEO);
                    label_Patient.Text = "Neonate";
                    label_Pump.Text = "100 mmHg";
                    V_Pumpup = 0;
                }
                else if (label_Patient.Text == "Neonate")
                {
                    Send_command(SETADULT);
                    label_Patient.Text = "Adult";
                    label_Pump.Text = "160 mmHg";
                    V_Pumpup = 3;
                }
            }
        }

        private void button_Pump_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (label_Status.Text == "IDLE")
            {
                if (label_Patient.Text == "Neonate")
                {
                    if (V_Pumpup < 2)
                        V_Pumpup++;
                    else
                        V_Pumpup = 0;
                }
                if (label_Patient.Text == "Adult")
                {
                    if ((V_Pumpup < 4) && (V_Pumpup >= 2))
                        V_Pumpup++;
                    else
                        V_Pumpup = 2;
                }
                switch (V_Pumpup)
                {
                    case 0:
                        Send_command(SETPMP100);
                        label_Pump.Text = "100 mmHg";
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        Send_command(SETPMP120);
                        label_Pump.Text = "120 mmHg";
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        Send_command(SETPMP140);
                        label_Pump.Text = "140 mmHg";
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        Send_command(SETPMP160);
                        label_Pump.Text = "160 mmHg";
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        Send_command(SETPMP180);
                        label_Pump.Text = "180 mmHg";
                        break;
                }
            }
        }

        private void button_Start_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (label_Status.Text == "IDLE")
            {
                Send_command(STARTMEAS);
                //Ser_Stat = RPRESS;
                label_Status.Text = "MEASURE";
                label_Statusstring.Text = "";
                label_Sys.Text = "";
                label_Dia.Text = "";
                label_Pulse.Text = "";
            }
        }

        private void button_Mano_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (label_Status.Text == "IDLE")
            {
                Send_command(SETMANO);
                label_Map.Text = "";
                //Ser_Stat = RPRESS;
                label_Status.Text = "Manometer";
            }
        }

        private void button_Leak_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (label_Status.Text == "IDLE")
            {
                if (label_Patient.Text == "Neonate")
                {
                    button_Patient.PerformClick();
                }
                Send_command(SETLEAK);
                //Ser_Stat = RPRESS;
                label_Status.Text = "Leaktest";
                label_Statusstring.Text = "";
                label_Sys.Text = "";
                label_Dia.Text = "";
                label_Pulse.Text = "";
            }
        }

        private void button_Break_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Send_command(STOPMEAS);
            label_Status.Text = "IDLE";
            V_Map = 0;
            label_Sys.Text = "---";
            label_Dia.Text = "---";
            label_Pulse.Text = "---";
            label_Map.Text = "---";
        }

        string buffer = "";
        private void serialPort1_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            while (serialPort1.BytesToRead > 0)
            {
                buffer += serialPort1.ReadTo("\r");
                int index1 = buffer.IndexOf('\u0002');
                int index2 = buffer.IndexOf('\u0003', index1 + 1);
                string buf = "";
                if ((index1 >= 0) && (index2 > index1))
                {
                    buf = buffer.Substring(index1 + 1, (index2 - 1 - index1));
                    buffer = buffer.Remove(index1, (index2  - index1));
                    this.BeginInvoke(new displayDeleg(display), new object[] { buf });
                }
            }
        }

        private void display(string message)
        {
            label_Statusstring.Text = message;
            label_Statusstring.ForeColor = Color.Black;
            if (message.Length > 3)
            {
                if ((message.Substring(5, 1)).Contains("S"))
                {
                    string temp = message.Substring(6, 1);
                    switch (temp)
                    {
                        case "3":
                            label_Status.Text = "MEASURE";
                            break;
                        case "4":
                            label_Status.Text = "Manometer";
                            break;
                        case "7":
                            label_Status.Text = "Leaktest";
                            break;
                        default:
                            label_Status.Text = "IDLE";
                            break;
                    }

                    label_Map.Text = message.Substring(0, 3);
                    if (label_Map.Text != "")
                        V_Map = Convert.ToInt16(label_Map.Text);
                    if (V_Map < 300) { }
                        bar1.Value = V_Map;
                }

                else
                {
                    if ((message.Substring(0, 1)).Contains("S"))
                    {
                        string temp = message.Substring(1, 1);
                        switch (temp)
                        {
                            case "2":
                                label_Statusstring.ForeColor = Color.Red;
                                break;
                            case "3":
                                label_Status.Text = "MEASURE";
                                break;
                            case "4":
                                label_Status.Text = "Manometer";
                                break;
                            case "7":
                                label_Status.Text = "Leaktest";
                                break;
                            default:
                                label_Status.Text = "IDLE";
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                    label_Map.Text = message.Substring(21, 3);
                    label_Sys.Text = message.Substring(15, 3);
                    label_Dia.Text = message.Substring(18, 3);
                    label_Pulse.Text = message.Substring(26, 3);

                    SaveData(
                        message.Substring(15, 3),
                        message.Substring(18, 3),
                        message.Substring(26, 3));
                }
            }
            else if (message.Contains("999"))
            {
                Send_command(READSTATUS);
                label_Status.Text = "IDLE";
                bar1.Value = 0;
            }
        }

        private void SaveData(string sys, string dia, string pulse)
        {
            try
            {
                string connectionString = @"Data Source=PLUTO-PC\;AttachDbFilename=C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\spiediena_merisana.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True";
                using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
                {
                    string queryString = "INSERT INTO merisana1 (sys, dia, pulse) VALUES (@sys, @dia, @pulse)";
                    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(queryString, connection);

                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sys", sys);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dia", dia);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pulse", pulse);

                    command.Connection.Open();
                    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
            }
            catch (SqlException ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
        }

        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            toolStripStatusLabel_time.Text = DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString();
        }
    } 

    public class VerticalProgressBar : ProgressBar
    {
        protected override CreateParams CreateParams
        {
            get
            {
                CreateParams cp = base.CreateParams;
                cp.Style |= 0x04;
                return cp;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what error you are getting ??

Comment: There are no errors, just nothing has been Inserted in DB..

Comment: Did you debug your code. Since you are handling exception, No runtime exception may notice to you?

Comment: I can't be sure because I don't have a database like yours, but the word SYS is a bit suspect here. Could you try to put square brackets around to do a little test?  `INSERT INTO merisana1 ([sys], dia, pulse...`

Comment: When I have this kind of problem I debug the program and when I reach in the ExecuteNonQuery() command , I copy the the sql command that's in the variable and try to run it directly in the SQL Server. Can you try this and tell me if it works?

Comment: There has to be some exception throwing which you are not debugging. Otherwise data must get inserted .

Comment: The string looks like S1;A0;C03;M00;P120080100;R075;T0005;;D2 , but im trying to send only 120 080 100 . And what data type I need to choose in DB side?

Comment: `pulse = message.Substring(26,3) = "075"`

Comment: It depends in what form you want to store them.The best guess is integer but as I told you this depends on you. 
Can you please try this:
`command.CommandText = string.Format("INSERT INTO merisana1 (sys, dia, pulse) VALUES ({0}, {1}, {2})",sys, dia, pulse);`

Answer (score 0):

Could you try this :

```
private void SaveData(string sys, string dia, string pulse)
{
    try
    {
        string connectionString = @"Data Source=(local);AttachDbFilename=C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\spiediena_merisana.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True";
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
           string queryString = "INSERT INTO merisana1 (sys, dia, pulse) VALUES (@sys, @dia, @pulse)";
           SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand (queryString, connection);        

           command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sys", sys);
           command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dia", dia);
           command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pulse", pulse);

           command.Connection.Open();
           command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
    catch (SqlException ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }

}
```

Comment: Rather than staring at almost the same piece of code, you should help by mentioning what changes are to be made or point out what is actually causing this error

Comment: Error 1 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand' does not contain a definition for 'connection' and no extension method 'connection' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Assuming that the connectionString is correct, I have just changed the way you execute a query to SQL Server. I have made it conformant with the documentation : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.aspx

@Sandis Menska : I have also updated the code.

Comment: Thank you! But nothing still happening.. Maybe I have done something wrong in DB side, im new in this all..

Answer (score 0):

Where is the message get set? Can you show us all your code?

Are your labels getting set to those substring values?

If yes, then can you try like -

```
SaveData(label_Sys.Text,
     label_Dia.Text,
     label_Pulse.Text);
```

I mean to use like -

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
           connection.Open();

         string queryString = "INSERT INTO merisana1 (sys, dia, pulse) VALUES (@sys, @dia, @pulse)";
           SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand (queryString, connection);        

           command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sys", sys);
           command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dia", dia);
           command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pulse", pulse);

           command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
```

Comment: Didn't get all answers. Are your labels getting set to those substring values? Ok... one more thing.... you are opening connection after the parameters are added. Could you please open it first and then create command object.

Comment: yes they are, I tried to send  those strings just to txt fail, all works, and I didnt understand your last suggestion..

Comment: Can you run sqlprofiler and check whether it is connecting to sqlserver and what is the query it is firing against it? I doubt that it is not making connection at all.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to start debugging on Sql server by running a profiler. If there isn't any kind of error on Front end, there would have been a call sent to Sql server.

Answer (score 0):

It seems there 's error in your connection string  try this connection string

`string connectionString = @"Data Source=PLUTO-PC\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\spiediena_merisana.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True"`;

Comment: I use sql server 2008 r8 and VB2010 and I have 2 instances, one is local (MSSQLSERVER) and SQLEXPRESS and Im using the first one

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all! My problem was incorect connectionstring! This is the right one!

```
 string connectionString = @"Data Source=PlUTO-PC\;Initial Catalog=merisana;Integrated Security=True";
```

I discovered it in left sidepanel called Server Explorer, where I didn look at all!